# How to delete all files from directory (not) matching some criteria?

Tags: ruby

Suppose, I have a following list of files within `app` directory:

```
$ tree app
app
└── lib
    ├── 3682_garbage.rb
    ├── 2639_grey.rb
    ├── 2311_blue.rb
    ├── 8276_garbage.rb
    └── 3672_garbage.rb
```

How could I delete all the files with `garbage` match on this directory? Afterwards, the directory should look like:

```
app
└── lib
    ├── 2639_grey.rb
    └── 2311_blue.rb
```

And how do I perform deletion the other way around, i.e. file names not containing `garbage`?

```
app
└── lib
    ├── 3682_garbage.rb
    ├── 8276_garbage.rb
    └── 3672_garbage.rb
```

I know in this case `Dir.glob` method can be used, but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that doesn't use `Dir#glob`?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill No, the answer easily could use Dir,glob.

Comment: @Ilya nailed it, then.  :D

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, I've missed part of question in first time)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I am actually also interested in the opposite deletion. Delete any file in the lib except garbage ;)

Comment: Did you do any search on internet for answer before posting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dir.glob`

```
Dir.glob("*garbage.*")
#=> ["3682_garbage.rb", "8276_garbage.rb", "3672_garbage.rb"]
```

To select files not matching a criteria, just subtract the matching files from all the files using the [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) method.

```
Dir.glob("*") - Dir.glob("*garbage.*")
#=> ["2639_grey.rb", "2311_blue.rb"]
```